# Dijkstra's algorithm in C, want the path

Tags: c, algorithm, dijkstra

I'm trying to implement the Dijkstra algorithm in C, I understand the algorithm and know how it works, but I just don't know how I can catch the path it does. Do anyone have a clue?

```
#include <limits.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define INF 1000
#define NUM_OF_NODES 4
#define MEMBER 1
#define NOMEMBER 0

void dijkstra(int weight[][NUM_OF_NODES],int s,int t,int *pd, int precede[])
{
    int distance[NUM_OF_NODES],perm[NUM_OF_NODES],prev[NUM_OF_NODES];
    int current,i,j,k,dc;
    int smalldist,newdist;
    for (int i = 0; i < NUM_OF_NODES; i++)
    {
        perm[i] = NOMEMBER;
        distance[i] = INF;
        prev[i] = -1;
    }

perm[s] = MEMBER;
distance[s] = 0;
current = s;

while(current != t)
{
    smalldist = INF;
    dc = distance[current];
    for (int i = 0; i < NUM_OF_NODES; i++)
    {
        if (perm[i] == NOMEMBER)
        {
            newdist = dc + weight[current][i];
            if (newdist < distance[i])
            {
                distance[i] = newdist; // Count the updated distance
                precede[i] = current;

            }
        if (distance[i] < smalldist)
        {
            smalldist = distance[i];
            k = i;
        }

        }
    }//end of for and if

    current = k;
    perm[current] = MEMBER;

}//end while
*pd = distance[t];
} //end of function
```

The output I want out from the program is 0 - > 3: 13 or something like that...

Comment: and what's the issue ?

Comment: Describe "0->3:13" in more detail. I don't know what you want as an output.

Comment: does your code compile?

Comment: @Philip It possibly means "The distance from 0 to 3 is 13".

Answer (score 2):

As far as I can tell you have the array of preceding nodes right there.

In which case outputting your path should be as simple as going through that

```
void print_path(int s, int t, int precede[]) {
    int current = t;

    while (current != s) {
        printf("%d -> ", current);
        current = precede[current];
    }

    printf("%d\n",current);
}
```

WIll print one shortest path from `t` to `s`.

**Edit**

Run as:

```
int precede[NUM_OF_NODES];
dijkstra(weight,s,t,pd, precede);
print_path(s,t,precede); // will print shortest a path from t to s
```

Comment: Thank you for you're answer, but what can I do if I want the whole path? For example I want to go from node 0 to 3. I will get the cost from pd which holds it. But say that I want an output like this. 0 -> 2 -> 3, so I know which way I should go. Have tried out several of the variables but with no success. Any clue?

Comment: @user1086801 that's exactly what my function prints. I edited it to add the invocation.